# Python2.7: reading a gzfile content inside a zipfile

Tags: python-2.7

Hello I was wondering if there is a way of reading a unformatted file which is stored in gzformat that is stored in zipformat. also this should be done without extracting any file format and outside pluggin than what python 2.7 can provides.

I just want to read entire or line (depending on minimal for memory usage) of the content if there is a bunch of gz in a zipfile then store it in a txt format outside. 
My code as of now can read out .log, .gz, .zip also .zip in a zip.
the idea is that it should repeat itself until we get the main file !
Thanks in advance :=)

.zip--->.gz--->unformattedfile

```
def decompress_file(filepath,type,file=None):
result = {}
if type.lower() == '.log':
     if file ==None:
         inFile = open(filepath, 'r')
         return getLog(inFile)
     else:
         return getLog(file)


if type.lower() == '.gz':
    if file == None:
        inFile = gzip.open(filepath, "r")
    else:
        #content = io.BytesIO(file.read())
        with file:
            Gz_file= open(file,'r')
            for gzFiles in file.namelist():

                zFile=file.getinfo(file)
                return getLog(zFile)

    return getLog(inFile)
    print inFile
    return getLog(inFile)

if type.lower() == '.zip':
    if file == None:
        with zip.ZipFile(filepath,'r'):
            zFile = zip.ZipFile(filepath)
    else:
        with zip.ZipFile(file,'r'):
            zFile = zip.ZipFile(file)

    for f_list in zFile.namelist():
        content= io.BytesIO(zFile.read(f_list))
        pattern = r'(.+)(?P<file>\.zip|\.gz)'
        rgz = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
        m = rgz.match(f_list)
        if m==None:
            type = '.log'
            decompress_file(f_list,type,zFile)
        else:                
           decompress_file(f_list,m.group('file').lower(),content)
    return result
return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
decompress_file("filepath",'.zip' )
```